Difference between gerund and a present participle
I saw him dancing.  In this sentence is dancing a present participle or a gerund?

Traditional grammar calls it a present participle.

I saw him dancing - verb. I saw his dancing - gerund (noun). It's certainly not a present participle in When I saw him he was dancing.

Does this answer your question? Gerund vs Present participle: "We’re depending on him finishing the job by Friday." Also What's the difference between a gerund and a participle? and many, many more.

@FumbleFingers It most certainly is a present participle in "... he was dancing". The progressive aspect is formed by means of auxiliary "be" + present participle.

@BillJ: I'll believe you. But I can't really see the point of such terminology for most people, regardless of whether they already know, or are trying to learn English. Nobody ever taught me such things, as is obvious!

On the Quirk et al noun-verb gradience model (I don't know how 'traditional' this school is) it's towards the verbal endpoint (the present participle) but not actually there. Quite verby. 'I saw him dancing' is the ACC-ing construction; 'I saw his dancing' is the POSS-ing structure (more formal). The POSS-ing structure has a more nouny ing-form. 'I don't like him dancing' focuses on the performing of the activity (he perhaps should be resting his knee); 'I don't like his dancing' focuses on the nominal referent (his dancing is almost as bad as mine. Let him do it in private, if he has to,)
